# Error on running a Ionic 3 App in Xcode "Property 'isPairedWatchExist' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate"

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, build, ionic3

I'm trying to run a app build on Ionic 3 on Xcode.

The app was running fine o Xcode in June when I have made and publish i Apple Store.

Now when I try to run the app on Xcode I receive this error "Property 'isPairedWatchExist' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate".

I receive the error from a file called CDVAppleWallet.m coming from the plugin cordova-apple-wallet that we use in application

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0NKz.jpg

I have tried to:

- run npm install;

  - uninstall the cordova apple wallet plugin and install it again;
- event the plugin is uninstalled we receive the error;

  - I have deleted all the plugins and node modules and reinstall them again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this too, and I did a few things but not sure which ones solved it:

- Removed platform, and re-added ios

> ```
> ionic cordova platform rm ios
> ionic cordova platform add ios
> ```

- Fixed signing in Xcode, exited
- Did a build in CLI

> ```
> ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
> ```

- Opened Xcode again, clicked "Clean Build Folder"

The error disappeared after that